# Add friend function using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'd like to add an add friend system to my website. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

`<a href="" id="add_friend">Add this user</a>!`

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_friend').click(function(){
        return false;
        var id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "friendID="+id,
            url: 'add_friend.php',
            success: function(){
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

add_friend.php:

```
<?php
 //level of error reporting
 error_reporting(0);

 //get session id
 include_once 'session.php';

 //get database connection
 include_once "includes/base.php";

 if (!empty($_POST['friendID']))
 {
  $friendID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['friendID']);

  $sql="INSERT INTO users_friends (userID, friendID, status) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$friendID."','1')";

 mysql_query($sql);
}

?>
```

As it stands when I click the link nothing happens. The page doesn't refresh, nothing.

Any ideas?

Also, I'd like it to update with the 'add this user' link with the fact that the user request has been sent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You've got `return false` as the first operation in your click call, which means it's a null-op: Execution never actually reaches the .ajax() call to begin with.

Comment: I was told that was required to stop the page from refreshing? In any case, I've taken that out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `return` immediately "returns" from a function call. It'd have to be the LAST thing in the click handler. As well, the jquery way to stop things is to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Check if the script is actually hitting your server. monitor the access logs while you do the clicking, etc... you have to do some debugging yourself, because other than the return stuff, the above code looks "ok".

Comment: Is it possible to call the function from a link as I'm doing? I'm debugging it with jsfiddle and it's giving me an error. It's telling me I need to use a post request. I tried using a form instead (with method specified as 'post') but it's still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/Qfk73/

Comment: It's ok, got it. I just used a form instead, replacing the submit button with a text link. That worked.